# Angular2 - Forward field validation in custom Component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-components

I am creating a custom form control component (email) that contains an input field, I forward the value of the input field (done correctly) but also want to **forward its errors**.

Using the following code I successfully pass the field's errors when the input changes but it does not pick up the **initial** errors correctly.

For example this email field will still report errors = {'required':true} even after the view is fully loaded and a value of 'example@email.com' is passed to it. Starting to type in the field and it will pass the errors correctly.

So my question is, **how can I pass the errors after the initial load of data?**

note: the problem is resolved by running this.propagateChange(this.value); in DoCheck lifecycle but I don't like it, I need something that is more efficient but no other hook seems to do the trick.

Here is the example:

```
import {Component, forwardRef, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, NgModel} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-email',
  template:`<form-group
  [errors]="{'required':'Email required', 'email':'Invalid email format'}"
  [info]="'Email*'"
>

  <input
    type        = "email"
    name        = "email"
    class       = "form-control"
    [(ngModel)] = "value"
    placeholder = "{{placeholder}}"
    (input)="onChange()"
    email
    required
    #f          = "ngModel"
  >
  {{f.errors | json}}
</form-group>`,
  styleUrls: ['./email.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputEmailComponent), multi: true },
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputEmailComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class InputEmailComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {


  value:String = null;

  @ViewChild('f') f:NgModel;

  @Input()
  placeholder:String = "Email";

  propagateChange:any = (val) => {};

  constructor() {}



  onChange(){
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
  }

  /**
   * Write a passed NgValue value to the element.
   */
  writeValue(value) {
    if (value && this.value != value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Set the function to be called
   * when the control receives a change event.
   * registers 'fn' that will be fired when changes are made
   * this is how we emit the changes back to the form
   */
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  /**
   * Set the function to be called
   * when the control receives a touch event.
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn) {}


  /**
   * Set the function to be called
   * to validate if input has errors.
   */
  validate(c: FormControl):any {

    console.log('validate email');
    return this.f.errors;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be resolved by using NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS instead of NG_VALIDATORS,
I am posting here the solution that worked for me:

```
import {Component, forwardRef, Input, ViewChild, KeyValueDiffers} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, FormControl, NgModel,
  NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS
} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
  selector: 'input-email',
  templateUrl: './email.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputEmailComponent), multi: true },
    { provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputEmailComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class InputEmailComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {


  value:String = null;
  differ: any;

  @ViewChild('f') f:NgModel;

  @Input()
  info:String = "Email";

  @Input()
  placeholder:String = "Email";

  propagateChange:any = (val) => {};

  constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    this.differ = differs.find({}).create(null);
  }

  onChange(){
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
  }

  /**
   * Write a passed NgValue value to the element.
   */
  writeValue(value) {
    if (value && this.value != value) {
      this.value = value;
      //setTimeout(()=>{this.propagateChange(this.value);},0)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Set the function to be called
   * when the control receives a change event.
   * registers 'fn' that will be fired when changes are made
   * this is how we emit the changes back to the form
   */
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  /**
   * Set the function to be called
   * when the control receives a touch event.
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn) {}


  /**
   * Set the function to be called
   * to validate if input has errors.
   */
  validate(c: FormControl):any {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Observable.of(c)
        .debounceTime(300)
        .switchMap(val => {
            return Observable.of(val.errors);
        })
        .subscribe(result => {
          console.log('RESOLVING ASYNC VALIDATOR: ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
          resolve(result);
        });
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into trouble employing your proposal because of the issue [FormGroup & FormControl statusChanges are not emitted on creation #14542](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14542).

Therefore I went with sync. validators like this:

```
export class MyInputComponent implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  ...
  @ViewChild('datePicker') public datePickerInput: NgbInputDatepicker;
  ...
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);

    // Force restart of validation
    if (this.ngControl && this.ngControl.control) {
      this.ngControl.control.updateValueAndValidity({
        onlySelf: true
      });
    }
  }
  ...
  public validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.datePickerInput ? this.datePickerInput.validate(control) : null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by calling the `onValidatorChange` callback (from the `Validator` interface) in `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Force the validation to trigger after the view has been initialised
    // otherwise the initial value is not marked as invalid
    if (this.onValidatorChange) {
      // you need a setTimeout here to make the change after Angular's change detection
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.onValidatorChange();
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onValidatorChange = fn
  }
```